# Integer Programming with RGLPK

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linear-programming

I'm trying to use the rglpk gem (https://github.com/wtaysom/rglpk) to solve an optimization problem with integer constraints. The readme gives an example of using the gem to solve a linear programming problem (simple - no integer constraints). Does anyone know how to modify the example to solve the problem if the solution was forced to be all integers?

The gem appears to support MIP solving, but I can't seem to get it to work. The below is what I've tried, without success. It results in this output:

> glp_intopt: optimal basis to initial LP relaxation not provided
>
> z = 0; x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 0

Here's the example with my attempt at modifying it:

```
# maximize
#   z = 10 * x1 + 6 * x2 + 4 * x3
#
# subject to
#   p:      x1 +     x2 +     x3 <= 100
#   q: 10 * x1 + 4 * x2 + 5 * x3 <= 600
#   r:  2 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 6 * x3 <= 300
#
# where all variables are non-negative AND INTEGERS
#   x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0
#  
#
p = Rglpk::Problem.new
p.name = "sample"
p.obj.dir = Rglpk::GLP_MAX

rows = p.add_rows(3)
rows[0].name = "p"
rows[0].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 100)
rows[1].name = "q"
rows[1].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 600)
rows[2].name = "r"
rows[2].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_UP, 0, 300)

cols = p.add_cols(3)
cols[0].name = "x1"
cols[0].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0)
cols[0].kind = Rglpk::GLP_IV #Force variable to be integer in solution
cols[1].name = "x2"
cols[1].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0)
cols[0].kind = Rglpk::GLP_IV
cols[2].name = "x3"
cols[2].set_bounds(Rglpk::GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0)
cols[0].kind = Rglpk::GLP_IV

p.obj.coefs = [10, 6, 4]

p.set_matrix([
                 1, 1, 1,
                 10, 4, 5,
                 2, 2, 6
             ])

p.mip
z = p.obj.mip
x1 = cols[0].mip_val
x2 = cols[1].mip_val
x3 = cols[2].mip_val

printf("z = %g; x1 = %g; x2 = %g; x3 = %g\n", z, x1, x2, x3)
#=> z = 733.333; x1 = 33.3333; x2 = 66.6667; x3 = 0
```

Comment: See [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glpk/2008-10/msg00017.html). More generally, Google on "glp_intopt: optimal basis to initial LP relaxation not provided".

Comment: That does it. Thanks! Just needed to add this line: "p.simplex" before "p.mip".

(I tried googling - that's definitely the top result, I must have missed it).